# Codeigniter insert dynamically multiple input fields into the database?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, controller

I'm working on a small web application where I want to insert multiple dynamic fields values into the database using Codeigniter, Unable to insert the `addmore` and `type` fields values into the database? I want insert single or multiple values into the database?

**Html**

```
     <form name="add_name" method="POST" action="AddMoreController/storePost">

        <div class="table-responsive">  
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                <tr>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="addmore[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" required="" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" required="" /></td>
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
        </div>


     </form>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){      
  var i=1;  


  $('#add').click(function(){
       i++;
       $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><input type="text" name="addmore[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" required /></td></tr><tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><input type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" required /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
  });


  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });  


});
```

**Controller**

```
public function storePost()
 {
    $nameArr = $_POST['addmore'];
    $emailArr = $_POST['type'];
    if(!empty($nameArr)){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($nameArr); $i++){
            if(!empty($nameArr[$i])){
                $data['name'] = $nameArr[$i];
                $data['type'] = $emailArr[$i];

                $this->db->insert('tagslist',$data);
            }
        }
    }

   print_r('Record Added Successfully.');
}
```

Comment: what problem you get?

Comment: what is `addmore[][name]` & `type[][name]` in input fields?

Comment: @KUMAR unable to store the values into the database?

Comment: can you solved your problem or not?

Comment: @KUMAR thanks problem is solve now

Comment: if your Problem is solved than marked my answer as a accepted answer please.

Answer (score 0):

**Change Your Controller Code :-**

```
    public function storePost(){
    
    $nameArr = $_POST['addmore'];
    $emailArr = $_POST['type'];
    if(!empty($nameArr)){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($nameArr); $i++){
            if(!empty($nameArr[$i])){
                $data = array(
                    'col_name' => $nameArr[$i],
                    'col_name' => $emailArr[$i]);

                $this->db->insert('tagslist',$data);
            }
        }
    }

   print_r('Record Added Successfully.');
}
```